# Change log output to configuration file in linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk

basically I have an output from a DHCP server log that looks something like this:

```
  hardware ethernet 00:16:41:ef:9e:47;
  client-hostname "mo-10";
  hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:20:a5;
  client-hostname "mo-11";
  hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:20:a5;
  client-hostname "mo-11";
  hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:20:a5;
  client-hostname "mo-11";
  hardware ethernet 00:16:41:ef:9e:47;
  client-hostname "mo-10";
  hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:21:35;
  client-hostname "mo-23";
```

Each two lines come together - the first is the MAC address of a device on the network and the second is the hostname. I would like to take the list, and put each pair of lines into a config block for my dhcp server like this:

```
    host mo-10 {
            hardware ethernet 00:16:41:ef:9e:47;
            fixed-address 192.168.1.10;
    }
```

The part after host should be identical to client-hostname, the hardware ethernet block should be the same and the fixed address should always be 192.168.1.x where x is the number in the host name (so for host mo-10 the ip should be 192.168.1.10, mo-23 would be 192.168.1.23 etc.) Everything should be enclosed in curly brackets.  Additionaly there are many duplicate entries, which I would like to remove. I tried messing around with grep and awk, but I'm not very proficient at manipulating text in bash and this is just too complex for me. I would be glad if somebody could provide a way to accomplish this and explain why it works.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the left hand spacing correct?  Does each line in the source start with several spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
awk '
NR%2 { eth = $0; next }
{ gsub(/[";]/,""); map[$NF] = eth }
END {
    for (host in map) {
        split (host, t, /-/);
        print "host " host " {\n\t" map[host], RS, "\tfixed-ethernet 192.168.1."t[2]";" RS "}"
    }
}' file
host mo-10 {
    hardware ethernet 00:16:41:ef:9e:47;
    fixed-ethernet 192.168.1.10;
}
host mo-11 {
    hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:20:a5;
    fixed-ethernet 192.168.1.11;
}
host mo-23 {
    hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:21:35;
    fixed-ethernet 192.168.1.23;
}
```

Store the odd lines in a variable `eth`. For even lines, you remove the quotes and `;` and create a hash keyed at hostname with value of line. In the `END` block you iterate over your hash and split the hostname on `-`.

Then you just print as your desired output.

Comment: +1 for using `awk`. Having the restriction to remove duplicates, it is more efficient then sed. (At least I don't know an efficient way with sed atm.. will try to find one ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, simple and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed. To remove duplicates I would suggest a pipe:

```
sed '/hardware/{N;s/\n/ /}' < list | sort -k5 | uniq -f4 | sed -r 's/ *hardware ([^ ]*) ([^;]*); *.*"(.*\-(.*))";/host \3 {\n\thardware \1 \2;\n\tfixed-address 192.178.10.\4;\n}/'
```

The pipe flattens the two-line records into one line per record, then overhands them to sort/uniq and then to sed for the final formatting again.

Output:

```
host mo-10 {
    hardware ethernet 00:16:41:ef:9e:47;
    fixed-address 192.178.10.10;
}
host mo-11 {
    hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:20:a5;
    fixed-address 192.178.10.11;
}
host mo-23 {
    hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:21:35;
    fixed-address 192.178.10.23;
}
```

Btw, after all I would prefer the `awk` solution as it doesn't need to iterate over the data again and again. (Didn't read the *remove duplicates* restriction when gave the first version of this answer).

Answer (score 0):

The next:

```
perl -lanE '
    if(/^\s*$/){$.--;next}  #skip empty lines
    push @v, map {s/[^\da-f:]//ig;$_} $F[$.%2+1] }{ %h=@v;  #process    
#print
say qq[host mo-$h{$_} {
    hardware ethernet $_;
    fixed-address 192.168.1.$h{$_};
}] for keys %h

' <<EOF
hardware ethernet 00:16:41:ef:9e:47    ;

client-hostname "mo-10"   ;

hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:20:a5;

client-hostname "mo-11" ;
hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:20:a5 ;
client-hostname "mo-11";
hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:20:a5;
client-hostname "mo-11";
hardware ethernet 00:16:41:ef:9e:47;

client-hostname "mo-10";
hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:21:35;
client-hostname "mo-23";
EOF
```

prints

```
host mo-23 {
    hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:21:35;
    fixed-address 192.168.1.23;
}
host mo-10 {
    hardware ethernet 00:16:41:ef:9e:47;
    fixed-address 192.168.1.10;
}
host mo-11 {
    hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:20:a5;
    fixed-address 192.168.1.11;
}
```

Comment: fixed now - removes duplicates

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
import re, sys

template='''\
host {} {{ 
   hardware ethernet {}
   fixed-address 192.168.1.{};
}}'''

pat=re.compile(r'hardware ethernet ([^;]+;)\nclient-hostname ([^;]+;)')

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fin:
    di={k.rstrip(';').strip('"'):v 
            for v, k in pat.findall(fin.read())}

for k, v in di.items():
    ip=re.search(r'(\d+)$', k).group(1)
    print template.format(k, v, ip)
```

From Bash, running `python ip.pl log.txt` prints:

```
host mo-23 { 
   hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:21:35;
   fixed-address 192.168.1.23;
}
host mo-11 { 
   hardware ethernet 00:11:25:73:20:a5;
   fixed-address 192.168.1.11;
}
host mo-10 { 
   hardware ethernet 00:16:41:ef:9e:47;
   fixed-address 192.168.1.10;
}
```

The duplicate removal is performed by adding the data by host name to a dict, which can only have one value with each key value.